# How to force a while loop execute one runnable at a time.

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am trying to make a simple timer with uneven time intervals after each repetition.

I start as follows:

```
            case R.id.start:
                timerRuns = true;
                startCycle();
                break;
```

The cycle itself looks like this:

```
private void startCycle() {
        pomodoroLeft = numPomodoro;
        while(pomodoroLeft > 0) {
            pomodoroLeft--;
            actualSeconds = pomodoroLength * ONE_MINUTE;
            setTimeAndRun(actualSeconds);
            actualSeconds = shortLength * ONE_MINUTE;
            setTimeAndRun(actualSeconds);


        }
    }
```

Method call:

```
 private void setTimeAndRun(long timePeriod) {
        runTime = timePeriod;
        runnable.run();
    }
```

And finally runnable itself:

```
private Runnable runnable = new Runnable()
    {

        public void run() {

            if (timerRuns) {
                runTime -= ONE_SECOND;
                String str = String.format("%1$02d : %2$02d",
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(runTime),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(runTime) -
                                TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(runTime))
                );
                timeShown.setText(str);

                mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                if(timeShown.getText().toString().contentEquals("00 : 00")) {
                    stopClock();
                    //here goes the alarm.
                }
            }

        }
    };
```

My problem is that when I start the timer while loop seems to execute everything despite 
incompliete run() of the previous method call. As a consequence timeShown TextView displays this `actualSeconds = shortLength * ONE_MINUTE` right away and skips 1 second each second because 2 runnables are running at the same time.

I want to achieve sequential execution here. What would be the best way to do so? Maybe implementing non-anonymous subclass and instantiate it every time would help?

Also, if you have any other suggestions that would improve my code I would greatly appreciate.

Comment: I don't think `postDelayed(this,...)` causes the `run()` method to stop.  It tries to schedule a _second_ execution of the same `Runnable` to occur after 1 second, but the first `run()` keeps going, and it soon returns to the caller.  Unfortunately, I'm not real familiar with how to do this sort of thing on Android, so I'd better let others come up with solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at queues.

Here is a link to a similar question:

[How to implement a queue of runnables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7418549/how-to-implement-a-queue-of-runnables)

You should use the Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor%28java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory

And here is a tutorial about the Executor:

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/executorservice.html

here is also something that may help you understanding better multithreading in java:

[Understanding multi-threading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8999707/understanding-multi-threading)

hope this helps somehow.